# EWS OnSubscriptionError return error - Subscription is invalid

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using Streaming notification for event types - EventType.Created, EventType.Modified,  EventType.Deleted and EventType.Moved.
I run my application and notification subscription works fine in general.
But sometimes and randomly got next error:
"Subscription is invalid., This message indicates no more events will occur for this EventSink. Event = Event. TimeStamp = 11/4/2020 1:56:02 PM. Event type = MailboxMoveStarted, Object Type = None, .ObjectId = .."

The error description contains - Event type = MailboxMoveStarted, but EventType enum does not contain this [item](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/Enumerations/EventType.cs)

It happened on event OnSubscriptionError and then connection closed.
Problem was for O365 mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

So in my experience, when you are using streaming notifications, your code has to be prepared for all kinds of exceptions, particularly when going against O365.  The cloud infrastructure behind EWS is kind of fluid, so subscriptions will tend to die out on you over the course of a day or two, or even a few hours.  The event you are seeing may be a new notification type, and moving MBs around is a common thing for O365.  Best to just toss the subscription and resubscribe ASAP.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I recreated subscription after getting error, but then I have other problem with subscription limits - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-maintain-affinity-between-group-of-subscriptions-and-mailbox-server. I got error - You have exceeded the available subscriptions for your account. Remove unnecessary subscriptions and try your request again.

Comment: So if you're going against O365 and you have more than a handful of MBs to deal with, you have to use the impersonation feature, whereby the user your code runs under impersonates the user for the MB and thus does not hit the limits you see in the article you linked to.  Also be sure to unsubscribe the old, dead subscription so it does not lay around, consuming a count.

Comment: Ok, I will try to use unsubscribe first of all. And thank you!

Comment: Hi @SergiyBondar , is this issue still you are facing ?, can you help me on this ? , as i am getting this error frequently , even unsubscribe and recreate also not working for me.

Comment: Hi @Sudhakarsingh, for now I use next algorithm - when got error by OnSubscriptionError: 1.Close connection 2. Get all subs -  connection.CurrentSubscriptions 3. For each - sub.Unsubscribe() with try-catch. After using this count of errors decreased to few times

Comment: in my case this was happening due to security protocol and framework version, upgrading .net version fix this issue.